# SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for file_get_contents

Tags: wamp, file-get-contents

I used the function `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the data and store it into a MySQL database. At first everything went fine. After a few hours appear something like [this](http://s13.postimage.org/6hb3q7j8n/error3.png).

I use WAMP. Please help me solve this problem because I do not know what to do. Things like this always happen after a few hours.

Thank you.

Regards,
Darnin

Comment: This happened to me today when I tried to call `preg_replace_callback` with an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to see the warnings just add the line

```
error_reporting(0);
```

as the first line after opening php tag in the php file.